# SyntaxError: Unexpected token >

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, client

I am trying to start a local server I get this big blob of errors, can someone please tell me what is happening and how to fix this?

This is the error I get when I try `node bot.js`

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Client\src\Local Server>node bot.js
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Client\src\Local Server\bot.js:7

net.createServer(socket = > {
                      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

Source of bot.js

```
net = require('net');

var clients = [];

const char = String.fromCharCode(0);

net.createServer(socket = > {


    socket.setNoDelay(true);

clients.push(socket);

console.log("Connected.");

socket.on('data', data = > {
    var x = data.readFloatBE(0);
var y = data.readFloatBE(4);
update(socket, x, y);
})
;

socket.on('error', error = > {}
)
;

socket.on('close', () = > {
    clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
console.log("Closed.");
})
;

socket.on('end', () = > {
    // ...
}
)
;

function update(sender, x, y) {
    for (var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
        if (clients[i] !== sender) {
            clients[i].write(x + ":" + y + char);
        }
    }
}

}).
listen(8888, '127.0.0.1');


console.log("Listening at: 8888")
```

source of package-lock.json

```
{
  "lockfileVersion": 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply arrow functions don't have a space, replace `= >` with `=>`